# How to make logical sense of following problem with ratios/percentages

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages, ratio

I have the following variables

| L | M | T |
| --- | --- | --- |
| L1 | M1 | T1 |
| L2 | M2 | T2 |
| L3 | M3 | T3 |
| L4 | M4 | T4 |

where $L+M=T$

I want to calculate an approximate value for the 4s using the ratio between the 2s and 1s, and then multiply it with the 3s.

To make it clear:
$\frac{T2}{T1}T3=T4$

But, this is using only the totals. You could also do it one by one:
$\frac{L2}{L1}L3=L4$ etc.

Though, doing it this way results in $L4+M4\neq T4$

The math checks out for this, but I struggle to make sense of it logically. Why does this make sense from a logical perspective, and which way of doing it would be correct for my purposes?

Comment: There's no logical contradiction, because there is no mathematical argument for why the results **should** come out the same. There are a very limited number of things that **do** come out the same when you do operations on all parts of a sum; at the moment the only example I can think of is multiplying all terms by the same number. Here you are multiplying all terms by different numbers. As for which way is correct for your purposes, you have given no hint of what those purposes really are, so we cannot answer that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you wish that this was true:

$$\frac{L_2}{L_1}L_3+\frac{M_2}{M_1}M_3=\frac{T_2}{T_1}T_3$$

which is:

$$\frac{L_2}{L_1}L_3+\frac{M_2}{M_1}M_3=\frac{L_2+M_2}{L_1+M_1}(L_3+M_3)$$

which can be transformed to:

$$(L_1M_2-L_2M_1)(L_1M_3-L_3M_1)=0$$

(see [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=simplify+l_2l_3%2Fl_1%2Bm_2m_3%2Fm_1-%28l_2%2Bm_2%29%28l_3%2Bm_3%29%2F%28l_1%2Bm_1%29)), which is:

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}L_1&M_1\\L_2&M_2\end{bmatrix}\cdot \det\begin{bmatrix}L_1&M_1\\L_3&M_3\end{bmatrix}=0$$

Now, the determinant of a matrix is sort-of a measure [*how linearly independent its rows or columns are*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Linear_independence). It is closely related to the [volume of the parallelepiped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Volume_and_Jacobian_determinant) spanned by those rows, or columns. For $2\times 2$ matrices, the parallelepiped is just the parallelogram, the "volume" is just the *area*, and the determinant is the measure of how far those rows or columns are from being *proportional* to each other. (If proportional, the parallelogram becomes degenerate and its area is $0$.)

So this explains why the belief that the above is true sounds so "logical". It *will* be true if either $(L_1, M_1)$ and $(L_2, M_2)$ are proportional to each other, or if $(L_1, M_1)$ and $(L_3, M_3)$ are proportional to each other. Which often happens if you are observing some trend in real life.

And, of course, if neither of those pairs are proportional to each other, then the first formula above is, sadly, false.

---

I will refrain from answering your last question:

> ... which way of doing it would be correct for my purposes?

as I don't know what your purpose is, but you have to give up either $T_4=\frac{T_2}{T_1}T_3$ or $T_4=L_4+M_4$. You choose which one. You may preserve the other.

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic answer Stinking Bishop, very well explained. Seems like these logical fallacies won’t stop following me any time soon :)